# Python : Index error Raised by iloc function

Tags: python

I'am a newbie with python, i get an error while the machine learning script was running [error raised by iloc function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHZZN.png)

I tried to understand the cause of this problem so i was searching in similair cases and read about iloc function. 
can someone give me help to understand the possible causes of this error and how i can recover it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Great, so you've shown the error. But what about your code? Data? Expected result? Sorry, but we can't imagine your problem statement.

Comment: error is clear you passed an out of bounds index value, also if this is `pandas` then tag the question appropriately

Comment: @EdChum how i can recover this problem

Comment: @AKMN Use a valid positional indexer.

Comment: I reproduced the issue and i get the same error for the following code :
import pandas as pd
X=pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,0,0],'B':[0,0,0],'C':[0,0,0]},index=list('abb'))
y_r=[]
#print(X)
pd.Series(y_r).iloc[X.reset_index(drop=True).drop_duplicates(keep='first').index]

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-callable) that calling `iloc` with non-existent index raises this error.

```
dfl = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,2), columns=list('AB'))

dfl.iloc[[4, 5, 6]]
IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds

dfl.iloc[:, 4]
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```